# How to set the default value for only positive time

Tags: mysql, time, default

I have column with `TIME` type(`00:00:00`). I want to allow only positive values. So, `-05:30:00`, for example, would be invalid.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: I can't see a way without triggers.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to set a DEFAULT VALUE for the column, so if it recieve '-05:00:00' value it will set the value to '00:00:00'.*

You can depend on [`time_format( time, format )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) and if required on [`date_format( date, format )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) functions in `MySQL`. You also require `substring` and `locate` functions to parse.

To set a time field to with default or +ve part of time data, following examples helps you:

```
mysql> set @time_value='-23:51:48';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

***Example 1***:

```
mysql> insert
         into time_table( time_field )
         values ( if( locate( '-', @time_value ) = 1, '00:00:00', @time_value ) );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Let us see what is inserted:

```
mysql> select time_field from time_table;
+------------+
| time_field |
+------------+
| 00:00:00   |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Example 2***:

```
mysql> insert
         into time_table( time_field )
         values ( substring( @time_value, ( locate( '-', @time_value ) + 1 ) ) );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

***Example 3***:

```
mysql> insert
         into time_table( time_field )
         values
          ( substring( time_format( @time_value, '%H %k:%i:%s' ),
                       ( locate( ' ', time_format( @time_value, '%H %k:%i:%s' ) ) + 1 )
                     ) 
          );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

In this:

1. `H`: for Hour to return as `00` to `23`
2. `k`: for Hour to return as `0` to `23`
3. `i`: for Minutes, numeric `00` to `59`
4. `s`: for Seconds to return as `00` to `59`

Let us see what is inserted:

```
mysql> select time_field from time_table;
+------------+
| time_field |
+------------+
| 23:51:48   |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For more details on format specifier characters like `%k` refer to [`date_format( date, format )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Thats not what im trying to do...
I want to set a DEFAULT VALUE for the column, so if it recieve '-05:00:00' value it will set the value to '00:00:00'

Comment: @user1424332 Solution to set default value `00:00:00` on -ve time inputs is added.